# How to POST with AJAX using just an a tag

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have an `a` tag that is dynamically generated with database content, it includes a data-target that I capture in javascript when it is clicked on, this is an example of one of the generated buttons:

`<a href="#" data-target="edit/?id=1">Edit</a>`

Simple, right?

Now, what I do in the JS when it is clicked, is as so:

```
var $this = $(this),
    $target = $this.data("target"),
    $endpointURL = "";

$endpointURL = $target.split("?id=")[0];

$id = $target.split("?id=")[1];
```

This allows me to set the endpoint I want, in out example above, it would be "edit" and also set the id which is just a number at this point.

Now, I have to POST this ID to the edit endpoint to return the right info, correct?

So, here is my AJAX for that:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: '{"id": ' + $id + ' }',
        url: "../assets/scripts/php/" + $endpointURL,
        success: function (data) {
            $("#content-lockup").html(data);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log("error: " + textStatus + ", error thrown: " + errorThrown);
        }
    });
```

This does not throw an error and does indeed output a var dump of the $_POST array as I have set it to, however it doesnt contain my ID that I passed over, here is the code on the endpoint and a screenshot of the output:

```
<?php

var_dump($_POST);

?>
```

[image]

Why would the vardump on $_POST not contain the id that I passed over in the apparently successful AJAX request?

What I expect is that I can say on the endpoint, something like:

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
```

Maybe its something obvious that i'm doing wrong but yeah, any ideas?

Comment: Without digging through your code in more detail, use something like Firebug or Developer Tools in most browsers to watch exactly what is sent/received on the Network tab for this sort of troubleshooting

Comment: The console shows nothing, as I said, the AJAX does work, the PHP endpoint is not being passed the id though.

Comment: Heed my question **Why would the vardump on $_POST not contain the id that I passed over in the apparently successful AJAX request?** just before I explained what I expected to happen.

Comment: Console will output nothing if an error is not experienced. I'm trying to show you how to debug which will help you generally. Your comment about "Heed my question..." is totally unnecessary. I'm out.

Comment: @SkullDev deeper in dev tools ....network tab, can see exactly what is being sent in any request. Also $ajax docs would have helped

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's because you are passing a string to `data` that isn't form encoded

Make it an object and jQuery will encode it for you

```
data: {"id": $id },
```

If it's a string it needs to be in format

```
data: 'id=' +id + '&someOtherParam=' + somevar
```

Comment: I think it should be just `data: {"id":  $id  },`